# fstab SMB share not mounting with read write access to Windows 8 machine

Tags: 12.10, samba, windows-8, cifs

I am using windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.10 and the windows 8 machine is setup as a SMB share. I have read through the man page for cifs-mount, but now matter what I try, I cannot get the share to give me read and write access to the server. Ubuntu will not let me install smbfs as it is obsoleted, so I am unsure where to go from here. The command I am using is

```
//theip/Users /media/folder cifs domain=domain,username=user,password=secret,uid=me,rw
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must've been very tired when I was dealing with this. I just checked again and the command seemed to work fine when I changed it to

```
//theip/Users /media/folder cifs domain=domain,username=me,password=mypass,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,codepage=unicode,unicode 0 0
```

I found this on this page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Answer (score 3):

Using Ubuntu 12.10, and connecting to a NAS smb share.  I'd like to clarify that simply adding uid and gid seems sufficient.  I had the following entry in my fstab:

```
//server_name/share_name  /mount_point  cifs  user=user_name,password=pass_word,rw 0 0
```

When I would right-click, the options for Create New Document and Create New Folder were greyed out.  I could open files, but only Save As was available if I edited, and trying that would throw a permission error.

I added the following after my password:

```
uid=my_uid,gid=my_gid
```

I was then able to edit the files and create folders as normal.